# default python to use in a script

Tags: python

I outsmarted myself and created an error as a result of trying to be prepared.

On the first line of a script I placed
`#! /usr/bin/python`
and later upgraded python and installed a new module. Sure enough, the new python is now `/opt/local/bin/python` and I got errors. It took a bit of debugging before I found this.

Anyway, now that I have I am wondering what is the best way to run a script:

Should I:

1. use `python <myscript.py>` or
2. make it executable, add the environment on the first line, and use it from the command line `./<myscript.py>`

I like `2.` but upon upgrading or changing the default python, the script can break because it specifies a different install.

Then am I expected to go through all the scripts and update them?

Is there a way to make the current/default python override the one specified on line1 of the script or is there another way to make a script executable without explicitly stating which python it uses (ie, to use the default one)?

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/env python`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429511/why-do-people-write-usr-bin-env-python-on-the-first-line-of-a-python-script

Comment: Also see [PEP 394: The "python" Command on Unix-Like Systems](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/), which gives some more details. (It's mostly about Python 2 vs. 3 or 3.x vs. 3.y, and it assumes you already know the basics of shbang lines, the `env` command, and prior practice… but there's some useful info there.)

Comment: @isbadawi: You should write that up as an answer, with some explanation (unless you think this question needs to be closed as a dup).

Comment: @isbadawi, abarnet just beat me to it, but if you write that up as the answer, I'll check it. That was what I was after. Thanks

Comment: Also note that this is in the official tutorial under [Executable Python Scripts](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html#executable-python-scripts).

Comment: Thanks for that link at the top (1st comment), I did search, but not knowing what it was I was looking for, I didn't even see that post (in fact that particular post didn't come up in any of my searches—obviously not using the best search terms)

Answer (score 0):

Since the mentioned stackoverflow links do not have an accepted answer.  I'll answer it while giving my opinion.  I think the best solution for all python scripts is `#!/usr/bin/env python` as changing the python that runs is as simple as modifying the `PATH` environment variable.  This is much better than updating all scripts (assuming scripts are already this way).

Number 1 `python <myscript.py>` can be used first to test before `PATH` modification.